# How to print key and values from the following collection?

Tags: python, printing, format

I have the following collection that holds a dictionary:

```
 {'EHAM': [78, [55, 23]], 'EGLL': [67, [46, 21]], 'LOWW': [67, [44, 23]], 'LFPG': [75, [43, 32]]}
```

I'd like to print the collection in the following output data format:

```
 NAME    #TOTAL     #TK     #LA
 EHAM    78         55      23
 EGLL    67         46      21
 LOWW    67         44      23
 LFPG    75         43      32
```

Right now I'm getting the following ouput:

```
#NAME #TOTAL #TK #LA
 EHAM [78, [55, 23]]
 EGLL [67, [46, 21]]
 LOWW [67, [44, 23]]
 LFPG [75, [43, 32]]
```

This is the piece of code I'm using:

```
#print(topAirpots_dict)
print("\n#NAME"+ " #TOTAL"+ " #TK"+ " #LA\n")
for k in (top_dict):
    print(k,top_dict[k])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of elements in the list inside values of the dictionary doesn't change, the following solution works.

```
print("\n#NAME"+ " #TOTAL"+ " #TK"+ " #LA\n")
for k in (top_dict):
    print(k, top_dict[k][0], top_dict[k][1][0], top_dict[k][1][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most performant way but gives the wanted output:

```
print("\nNAME"+ " \t#TOTAL"+ " \t#TK"+ " \t#LA\n")
for k in (top_dict):
    first_val = top_dict[k][0]
    sec_val = top_dict[k][1][0]
    third_val = top_dict[k][1][1]
    print(k , " \t" , first_val , " \t" , sec_val , " \t" , third_val)
```

or faster but a bit harder to read:

```
print("\nNAME"+ " \t#TOTAL"+ " \t#TK"+ " \t#LA\n")
for k in (top_dict):
    print(k , " \t" , top_dict[k][0], " \t" , top_dict[k][1][0], " \t" , top_dict[k][1][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful:

```
my_dict = {'EHAM': [78, [55, 23]], 'EGLL': [67, [46, 21]], 'LOWW': [67, [44, 23]], 'LFPG': [75, [43, 32]]}

print("NAME", "#TOTAL", "#TK", "#LA", sep="\t\t")
for k, item in my_dict.items():
    total, other = item
    tk, tl = other
    print(f"{k} {total:>10} {tk:>10} {tl:>7}")
```

Output:

```
NAME        #TOTAL      #TK     #LA
EHAM         78         55      23
EGLL         67         46      21
LOWW         67         44      23
LFPG         75         43      32
```

used

**string formatting**-> [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/] &

**string interpolation**-> [https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/]